# How to replace spaces in URL having path parameter, with a hyphen or an underscore

Tags: python, flask

I am sorry if this Q makes no sense , but is there a way to replace spaces with hyphen in URL's(only) having used path parameter to build it ?

My scenario is as :

I have a view method as below:

```
from app.service import *

@app.route('/myapp/<search_url>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def search_func(search_url):
    print(search_url) // This prints 'hi-martin king' and i need to pass 'hi-martin king' to below with preserving space
    search_q = search(search_url) 
    return render_template('wordsearch.html',data=search_q['data'])
```

- here `search_url` I am passing from template

I have the `search` function which takes `search_url` as argument(`def search(search_url): .....`) and does all operations (for ref) which i have imported from service above.

Now when I run , i have the sample URL as,

```
....myapp/hi-martin%20king
```

Here I am preserving space to perform query in database (In db it is stored as `martin king`), but I don't want to show the same in URL instead replace it with a hyphen

I have other way that changing all the values in database (removing spaces but this is tmk not a appropriate solution)

### expected o/p:

```
....myapp/hi-martin-king  (or with an underscore) ....myapp/hi-martin_king
```

Here how can i preserve spaces to pass it as argument to the function and at the same time I want to replace only in URL ? Is this possible ?

Any help is appreciated ....TIA

Comment: Do you need to change the code(`%20`) to space(`'  '`)?

Comment: about expected output: `myapp/hi-martin-king` and `myapp/hi-martin_king` are different outputs ). could you add input string `search_url` and expected one output?

Comment: Yeah they both are different but I put that as to replace space with a hyphen or an underscore

Comment: sorry but I'm tired. seriously. anyway good luck!

Comment: tired of my question ? is my Q a valid one ? i'm afraid

Comment: As you can see you've got 3 the same answers ))) I mean(`replace`, `split` etc). So I think your question isn't valid. Try to rewrite question. By the way try to read about `nginx`, `rewrite rules` etc and how's it works with server side.

Comment: You didn't answer Danila's first question, and I think its the most important: *Why do you need to change the code(`%20`) to space(`' '`)*?

Comment: Just delete the question. People just waste time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query your db while preserving spaces you can just url-unescape them for the query using `urllib.parse.unquote` and preserve them escaped in the url as follows:

```
import urllib.parse

from app.service import *

@app.route('/myapp/<search_url>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def search_func(search_url):
    unquoted_search = urllib.parse.unquote(search_url)
    search_q = search(unquoted_search) 
    return render_template('wordsearch.html',data=search_q['data'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The string with `%` in needs **unquoting** if you want the raw version.

```
from werkzeug import url_unquote

url_unquote('hi-martin%20king')  # => 'hi-martin king'
```

Now you have the unquoted string, you can replace spaces with either a hyphen or an underscore.

```
replace_character = '-'

def fix_string(s):
    return s.replace(' ', replace_character)

fix_string('hi-martin king')  # => 'hi-martin-king'
```